# Objejctive-C - SQLite not writing to database file during unit testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an iOS application that uses SQLite as its database. For some reason, when I'm running unit tests involving SQLite operations, the created `*.sqlite` file will always be empty, but my class method calls to retrieve information from it will work just fine.

I've tested my application using the simulator and the resulting `.sqlite` file contains information by calling the same methods that the unit test is calling.

Is there a difference between running SQLite operations via the simulator/device, and via unit tests?

Comment: are you copying SQLite into documents directory ? are you opening it with ReadWrite option ?

Comment: @ogres The SQLite file is saved in the Library folder with: `NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.dbName];`